# How to output parts of layers (shapefiles) that do not intersect using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, intersection, kernel-density

I have two layers (shape files) that I want to select what do not intersect, to after all make a kernel of it.

How do I do that in ModelBuilder without scripting?

If someone can help me, even directing me to something to read, would be awesome.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the tool called "[symmetrical diffrence](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Symmetrical_Difference_%28Analysis%29)" to create a new feature class. If you don't have an advanced licence, you can make an union then select by attribute the features with one of the two origin ID field equal to -1

If you don't want it, you can select all feature (using select layer by attribute with SWITCH_SELECTION in model builder), then use select layer by location (with REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION in model builder) of those that intersect. more details [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000071000000)

Note that the two results will be different, because the first method will change the geometry and the second will not.

Comment: The second approach solved my problem. Thanks a lot!